# Change an elements height dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a div to get the height of another element if the class `collapsed` isn't in that element (I'm using bootstrap toggle collapse).

It works when the page is loaded but when I click on the element and the class `collapsed` is removed the `#careheight` doesn't change height.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divHeight = $("#care_and_washing").height();
  if (!$("#care_and_washing").hasClass("collapsed")) {
    $('#careheight').height(divHeight);
  } else {
    $('#careheight').height("10px");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="care_and_washing" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" class="collapsed" style="font-family: 'NiveauGroteskMedium'; font-size: 11px; color: black;">Care & Washing</p>

<div style="cursor: default; padding-left: 13px;" id="demo" class="collapse">
  <p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Dry Flat</p>
  <p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Do Not Bleach</p>
  <p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Tumble Dry Low</p>
  <p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Iron Low</p>
  <p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Hand Wash</p>
</div>

<div id="careheight"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the function is only called on the document load. You'll have to assign it to a click as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    changeHeight();
})

$('.element-you-want-to-click').click(function() {
    changeHeight()
});

function changeHeight() {
    var divHeight = $("#care_and_washing").height();

    if (!$("#care_and_washing").hasClass("collapsed")) {
        $('#careheight').height(divHeight);
    }

    else {
        $('#careheight').height("10px");
    }
}
```

This should work, if your initial function worked.

Comment: That's odd. Could you send me a link so I can check it out?

Comment: the code works tho i'ts just the click event that apparently doesn't...

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your problem from here, sorry =/

Comment: i think i found why, apparently bootstrap doesn't remove the class it toggles it with a space and by doing so it doesn't work on jsfiddle too

Comment: nvm it wasn't that .-.